# Understanding Poincare lemma

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, exterior-algebra

Poincaré's Lemma states that on a contracting manifold, all closed forms are exact. \

Can anyone explain me the following statement using Poincaré's Lemma?

Consider a function $G(x):\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, $m\leq n$. If $G(x)$ is integrable then Poincaré's Lemma ensures the existance of a function $\Gamma(x)$ such that $G(x)=\nabla_x\Gamma$.

where:
$\nabla_xG=\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial x}$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ need not be scalar. For example of $G(x)=\begin{bmatrix} x_1x_2\\ \dfrac{1}{2}x_1^2\end{bmatrix}$. This will give $\Gamma=\dfrac{1}{2}x_1^2x_2$.

Comment: What does $\nabla_x$ mean? I can only make sense of this question on $\Bbb R$, and it has nothing to do with the Poincaré Lemma.

Comment: If $G$ has more than two component, it is not called a function (or $0$-form)

Comment: Well, this looks false, then, unless your definition of "$G$ is integrable" is that the $1$-form $\sum G_i(x)\,dx_i$ is closed. That's not the usual interpretation.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I read this in a research paper. Wanted to confirm this. Is there a relation between Poincaré's Lemma and integrability?